# Sharing the DMA buffer file descriptor between the Linux user space processes

Tags: embedded, ipc, embedded-linux, dma

I have Process A and Process B in user space. The Process A allocates
the buffer from DMA pool and then it fills some data. Is it possible
for the Process A to share this data with the Process B by sending the file descriptor (alloc_data.fd)?

```c
void dma_buffer_allocation()
{
    int dma_heap_fd;
    struct dma_heap_allocation_data alloc_data;
    void* buffer;
    size_t buffer_size = 4096;  // Example buffer size

    // Open the DMA heap device
    dma_heap_fd = open("/dev/dma_heap", O_RDWR);
    if (dma_heap_fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open DMA heap device");
        return;
    }

    // Set the allocation data
    alloc_data.len = buffer_size;
    alloc_data.fd = -1;  // File descriptor placeholder for the allocated DMA buffer

    // Perform the DMA buffer allocation
    if (ioctl(dma_heap_fd, DMA_HEAP_IOCTL_ALLOC, &alloc_data) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to allocate DMA buffer");
        close(dma_heap_fd);
        return;
    }

    // Map the DMA buffer into user space
    buffer = mmap(NULL, buffer_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, alloc_data.fd, 0);
    if (buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Failed to map DMA buffer");
        close(dma_heap_fd);
        return;
    }

    // Use the DMA buffer
    // ...
    // Access and manipulate the buffer contents as needed

    // Unmap the DMA buffer from user space
    if (munmap(buffer, buffer_size) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to unmap DMA buffer");
    }

    // Close the DMA heap device
    close(dma_heap_fd);
}
```